# while reading a tiff file filenotfoundexception

Tags: geotiff-tiff, geotools

I am unable to create File object while instantiate a tiff file using TestData.file function it is giving file not found exception . But the tif file is exist on the same path

> file exists
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Can not
>   locate test-data for "images/no_crs.tif"  at
>   org.geotools.test.TestData.url(TestData.java:306)     at
>   org.geotools.test.TestData.file(TestData.java:328)    at
>   org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffTest.main(GeoTiffTest.java:17)

here is my code

```
public class GeoTiffTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
    {
    File file = new File("images/no_crs.tif");
    if(file.exists())
            System.out.println("file exists");
    else
            System.out.println("file not exist");
        final File noCrs = TestData.file(GeoTiffTest.class, "images/no_crs.tif");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TestData.file()` is a special class for creating paths to files stored in a folder called test-data under the package name of your class in the resource folder. See http://docs.geotools.org/latest/developer/conventions/test/data.html for a full description of what it does. So if your file is in images/ then it won't be found using the path returned by  `TestData.file()`;